# if statement in buildspec file - [[: not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, bash, shell, aws-codebuild

I am trying to add a conditional in my buildspec.yml for my CI/CD in Codebuild. The idea is that it compares an environment variable and depending on the comparison, does something. Like this:

```
SNYK_CODE_TEST=true

`if [ "$SNYK_CODE_TEST" == "true" ] ; then yarn run snyk-code-test ; fi`,
```

However, I am getting errors like this:

`/codebuild/output/tmp/script.sh: 4: [[: not found`

How should the conditional be?

Comment: The code you state and the code that's actually running don't match. The error is coming from code that tries to use `[[` (a ksh/zsh/bash extension) while running a copy of `sh` that doesn't offer that extension. Make sure you're providing a [mre] that others can use to reproduce the exact same problem when run without changes.

Comment: That said, the code you state is _also_ buggy for separate reasons when invoked with sh, because only `=` and not `==` is POSIX-guaranteed to be a valid string comparison operator. See the relevant specification at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html

Comment: BTW, do you really have the backticks in your code? They're almost certainly wrong, though we'd need more context to be sure.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Not really. I have them because I'm putting that into AWS CDK for the buildspec.yml. The code is really just that line and SNYK_CODE_TEST is set to true. ```if [[ "$SNYK_CODE_TEST" == "true" ]] ; then yarn run snyk-code-test ; fi```

Comment: Anyway, the point is that you shouldn't use bash extensions like `[[` and `==`. Limit yourself to POSIX shell features.